# Unix bidirectional pipe on commandline

Tags: linux, redirection, pipe, netcat

I've been able to use this linux command to connect Netcat to a serial port:

```
nc -l 80 <> /dev/ttyS0
```

I would like to be able to log this transaction.  My backup plan is to use Wireshark to monitor the netcat stream, but ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | tee upstream.bin | nc -l 80| tee downstream.bin | /dev/ttyS0
```

This tries to open ttyS0 twice and therefore throws a permissions error.  Does anyone know a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netcat documentation says

> To obtain a hex dump file of the data sent either way, use "-o logfile".  The
>   dump lines begin with "<" or ">" to respectively indicate "from the net" or
>   "to the net", and contain the total count per direction, and hex and ascii
>   representations of the traffic.  Capturing a hex dump naturally slows netcat
>   down a bit, so don't use it where speed is critical.